# Properties NOT marked with "[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]" are not being sent via JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

Here's my code:

```
[DataContract]
public class SideDto
{
    public SideDto() { }

    public SideDto(Side side)
    {
        SideId = side.SideId;
        Stage = side.Stage;
    }

    [Key]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int SideId { get; set; }

    public Stage Stage { get; set; }

}
```

When I call this, I get SideId, but I don't get Stage.  If I mark Stage as IsRequired, I get it, but then when I post a new Side with no Stage defined (since I don't actually need it for the data model, just presentation layer), I get an error.  Any idea how I can get these properties on the wire without such strict validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would just need to decorate the 'Stage' property with a DataMember attribute, *without* the  IsRequired.

Comment: @RobVious, we all have those moments